# Unable to remove locally installed (debug) add-in

Tags: office-js

I've been working on a JS add-in for Outlook for some time now, recently, I started having a problem with all add-ins (my local one and others from the store) failing to load when I launched the add-in project via VS2017.  Suspecting it might be environmental, I un/re-installed Outlook and Visual Studio.

When attempting to deploy a local build for debugging, the deploy failed, providing an unspecified error. When looking in Outlook, the add-in is still present from a previous install. When attempting to uninstall on the web I'm given this response:

> The app with the ID [Add-in GUID] is managed by the administrator for your organization and can't be uninstalled.
>   [image: Error message]

The add-in as listed as being installed by me, i.e. not an admin:
[image: Self Installed]

The uninstall button on the outlook 2016 client does nothing, and clicking on the add-in in the list of installed ones (which would normally send you to an info pane) returns an error.

The add-in was only installed via Visual Studio deploy, or occasionally via hosted manifest url when testing against deployed versions. I don't know how it can be removed, or how it ended up in this state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the following url and login with your office 365 credentials

https://outlook.office.com/owa/?path=/options/manageapps

From this page select the addin you want to remove and click on the remove icon

[image]

Comment: That is where error message quoted above is shown, on pressing the remove button.

Comment: You may need to do a Repair on your local Office installation (yes, I know that sounds crazy but it often fixes these issues)

Comment: That sorted me out. Strange, but we'll roll with it. Thanks.

Comment: I personally prefer side loading the add-in during development as well rather then deploying it on every time I run the project, this has fewer issues , check this link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/sideload-outlook-add-ins-for-testing